# jQuery common popup for a set of elements

Tags: jquery, css, popup

I want a popup so that I'm listing a lot of contacts and there is a provision for sending messages. Can I use a single popup and move it around the DOM such that when I click on a send message link the popup will be shown near the link I googled  and searched for it a while couldn't see a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the location of the dialog result using

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", [200,300] );
```

And you can get the mouse pointer location (which assuming the link is near the contact will be approximately the right location (you might need to tweek it)) so would something like this do the trick:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", [window.event.clientX,window.event.clientY]);

$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "open");
```

position --> http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position

mouse --> http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/29285